# supervised classification of multiple categories with a natural ordering

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I try to train a model to classify samples into three categories: `weak`, `medium`, and `strong`. As far as I know, the best way to do this is to use `weighted kappa score` to measure the model performance. It seems weighted kappa is not implemented in `scikit-learn`. How do people do with `scikit-learn` for this types of classification? It is a fairly routine task.

Comment: What's the question here? Is it implemented? No, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skll` to get the kappa score to measure the performance.

```
from skll.metrics import kappa
kappa_val = kappa(y_true, y_pred)
```

There are also many other use cases of `skll`. For details, please visit the link [here](http://skll.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/skll.html#from-metrics-module)

Comment: from skll.metrics import kappa throws an error "cannot import name BaseLibLinear". Curious if you have seen this issue before?

Comment: what version of skll are you using? I am using skll 1.0.1 and I do not get any error. `>>> import skll
>>> skll.__version__
'1.0.1'
>>> from skll.metrics import kappa
>>>`  is successful

Comment: Even I just now created a fresh conda environment with skll installed in it, and it works successfully. Please update your skll package.`$ conda create -n skll python=3.4 skll  $source activate skll $ python >>> from skll.metrics import kappa` is successful